# Why am I seeing slow response times from google cloud spanner?

Tags: python, google-cloud-spanner

I am in the process of migrating to google cloud spanner for an Django application, on GAE, and found the response times to be very long, in the order of 2-3 seconds for and indexed query which takes 10 ms when running in the spanner query editor.

It is also only the first query that takes this long, and any subsequent queries takes around 100 ms.

I encounter the same issue when running a bare minimum query with the python client, I've attached the code below:

```
from google.cloud import spanner_v1
client = spanner_v1.Client()

i = client.instance("my-instance")
db = i.database("my-database")

start = time.time()
with db.snapshot() as snapshot:
    QUERY = (
        """
            SELECT
              *
            FROM
              dates
            WHERE 
              date_id = 4507
        """)
    result = snapshot.execute_sql(QUERY)

    for row in result:
        print(row)

end = time.time()
print((end-start)*1000)
```

which in this case takes 1154 ms. Running the query again (without reinitialising the database object) takes 110ms.

Ill include some outputs from a line-profiler run on the function corresponding to db.snapshot():

```
Timer unit: 0.001 s

Total time: 1.05145 s
File: /Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_v1/database.py
Function: __enter__ at line 859

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   859                                               def __enter__(self):
   860                                                   """Begin ``with`` block."""
   861         1       1051.4   1051.4    100.0          session = self._session = self._database._pool.get()
   862         1          0.0      0.0      0.0          return Snapshot(session, **self._kw)
```

Running this python==3.8.0 and google-cloud-spanner==3.11.1 on a Mac.. Any help or ideas where to troubleshoot is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are seeing are down to the following:

1. The first query will be slower than the rest, as the first query will have to wait for the session pool that is used by the Python client to be created, and for at least one session to have been created and returned by Cloud Spanner. All subsequent queries will reuse sessions from the pool, which is why you are seeing a lot lower values from the second query on.
2. The total execution time for the second query will depend on the physical distance between your client and the Cloud Spanner instance and the network quality. I assume that the query is selecting one row based on the primary key (i.e. `date_id` is the only column in the primary key of the table). The client should preferably be running on a Google App Engine instance that is in the same physical region as your Cloud Spanner instance (e.g. both could be in the region `us-central1`, and not one in `us-east1` and one in `us-central1`).

If I understand you correctly, the numbers that you provided are based on executions locally from your own development machine. I think that a large part of the execution time difference that you are seeing (compared to the GCP Console) for the second and further queries, are due to network latency between your local machine and Cloud Spanner.

It would be interesting to see if you get better numbers if you execute the test query from a GAE instance or a simple Google Compute Virtual Machine that is in the same physical region as the Cloud Spanner database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was my initial thought as well, so in the case of the django front end the queries took between 2.5-3 seconds locally and once deployed to GAE they took about 850 ms. So indeed a bit of a performance boost but still, 850 ms response would mean around 840ms overhead, which seems very high (compare to about 120ms for the equivalent cloud sql instance). I ran the exact same code as I posted originally on a compute engine in europe-west1b (my spanner instance is in europe-west1) and it took 512 ms ± 17.8 ms, still very long right?

Comment: Are the numbers that you wrote in the above comment for the first query? Or for the second and following queries? Because to get a real indication of what a realistic execution time for only the query would be, it would be better to ignore the first query, as it will be too much influenced by (session pool) initialization. And yes, 512ms sounds like a lot (unless it is the first query).

Comment: No these numbers are for the first query, subsequent queries are very fast, 4.89 ms ± 139 µs. But alright, so this is expected behaviour? Then I guess my issue really lies with the django-google-spanner package, since it appears it creates a new session for each request, so the response time will be dependent on the execution time of the first query.

Comment: Yes, this is largely as expected. However, it is not really the first query that is slow, but the initialization of the session pool. That starts asynchronously when you call `i.database("my-database")`, but because you execute the first query directly after getting a reference to the database, the first query will first have to wait until the initialization has finished before it is executed. Also, I don't think it is intentional that the django-spanner package should create a new session for each query, so it might be worth opening an issue in the GitHub repository for that.